# Flowable bpmn: configure parent id for sub tasks in a process

Tags: java, bpmn, flowable

I'm using flowable engine api with java spring boot. I have a process that contains sub processes which have several tasks.
the problem is when the tasks are created automatically by the engine, it sets the parent task id with null.
Is there like an option when initiating the process to enable setting the parent id for the tasks automatically or how can i do this?
I need to have the previous task id with me at every step.